# ClassNotFoundException for net.sf.jga.parser.JFXGParser

Tags: java, dataset, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to understand what is incorrect about my code and trying to understand the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jga/parser/JFXGParser
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdesktop.dataset.DataSet.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.datamotion.DMNet.getMailbox(DMNet.java:358)
    at com.datamotion.Mailbox$1.actionPerformed(Mailbox.java:50)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jga.parser.JFXGParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 51 more
```

The only code in question is the following line:

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
```

DataSet is part of the 0.8 swingx api/library. I could really use some help with this.

UPDATE:
My imports:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.jdesktop.dataset.DataSet;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

Comment: So if you empty out your main and just put that one line you get the error? What do your imports look like?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be 5 months after the question was posted, but I hope it will help somebody.

I was working on a Java Application that had no issues, but once I started using the SwingLabs DataSet, I was unable to get the application to run, receiving the ClassNotFoundException with JFXGParser.

I created a new application with just the one line of code to create a DataSet

```
import org.jdesktop.dataset.DataSet;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("ds");
    }
}
```

Here is a snapshot of the package explorer to show what was referenced.

[image: Package Explorer]

Some answers online mentioned the Classpath, so I checked mine and the project seemed to have it, so I was still baffled. I decided to do something I didn't think would work, but it did. I noticed that the references were inside the "DataSetTester (default classpath)" folder. So instead, I decided to add the jars to the root "User Entries" Classpath. Once I did that, the application was running just fine.

Note: Some jars may not have been needed, but this is the setup that I used that was working. The DataSet object is part of the databinding-0.8.0.jar, but I think the jga-0.7.2-crrl.jar was also required.

[image: Properties for Application]

[image: Edit Configuration]

Step by Steps (for Eclipse):

1. Create new Java Application
2. Go to: Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries tab
3. Add jar files using "Add External JARs..."
4. Write code; Eclipse should have the autofill working if jars were added properly
5. Run application and receive ClassNotFoundException
6. Determine which jar has the class that is causing exception using debug
7. Go to: Project > Properties > Run/Debug Settings
8. Select the proper object for the launch configuration and click "Edit..."
9. Go to: Classpath tab
10. Select "User Entries" and click "Add External JARs..."
11. Add same jars files that were used in the Libraries
12. Run application (may need to perform clean)